# How to parse PostAsync response from Bing 2 API in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, httpclient, bing-api

Bing put out a new version (2) of their Search API several months ago.  MS Cognitive Services provides examples of using their new Search API 2.
https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/571fab09dbe2d933e891028f

However the worked examples are with XML responses and there is only a partial C# example which makes the call, but doesn't decode the result.

Can someone pls explain or continue the sample code in order to parse the returned object into actual images or image-URLs?  In the code below, the "content" variable is of type ByteArrayContent, but what is required to grab the information from this array?  The "response" variable is of type HttpResponseMessage, but how to extract images or image-URLs from it?

This would allow an application to  select and display one or more of the returned images.

Many thanks, Tim

Here's the C# code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace CSHttpClientSample
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MakeRequest();
            Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async void MakeRequest()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", 
            "{subscription key}");

            // Request parameters
            queryString["q"] = "cats";
            var uri = 
                "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?" 
                + queryString;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{body}");

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
               content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(
               "< your content type, i.e. application/json >");
               response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some trial & error, I found that inserting the following code converts the search "response" first into a string and then into a JSON object which can be parsed for Bing's various Search results.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
....
....
response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Stringr str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/DamienDoumer/BingO) is a really easy to use client API for the bing search API, you can get web search, pictures, news... from it too. Here is a small example of how to use it to get pictures from Bing search in C#.

```
    SearchResult result = await BingSearchHelper.Query("Bill Gates", new BingQueryParameters( apiKey: "APPKEY", count: 10, offset: 0, mkt: "en-us", safeSearch: "Moderate") );

Console.WriteLine(result.images.value[0].thumbnailUrl);
```

You don't need JSON or XML conversion if you will use it just for that purpose.
I hope it will help you.